# cannot get a response message with retrofit 2

Tags: java, php, android

I have a problem i try to get a message after passing a value to PHP file then how to show the value of massge
from within the php file I tried but I have an error message ,how do I get a message from the php file so that it is the result of the Non or Don message as written in the php file , see my code

```
  //  Log.i: msg: error loading from API java.lang.IllegalStateException:Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $


                // MainActivity class: 
                public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // updateList();
                                post_1();
                            }
                        }, 300);
                    }

                public void post_1(){
                    ApiUtil.getServiceClass().getAllPost("ahmed").enqueue(new Callback<List<ApiObject>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<ApiObject>> call,Response<List<ApiObject>>response) {
                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                List<ApiObject> postList = response.body();
                                Log.i("msg", "Returned msg " + response.message().toString());
                                //Log.i("msg", "Returned count " + postList.size());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<ApiObject>> call, Throwable t) {
                            //showErrorMessage();
                            Log.i("msg", "error loading from API "+t.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }



                    // End ;
                }

                // interface : 

                public interface RetrofitInterface {

                    @GET("get.php")
                    public Call<List<ApiObject>> getAllPost(@Query("name") String user_name);

                }
                // ApiUtil class : 
                public class ApiUtil {
                    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.3/test/";
                    public static RetrofitInterface getServiceClass(){
                        return RetrofitAPI.getRetrofit(BASE_URL).create(RetrofitInterface.class);
                    }
                }

            // ApiObject class : 
            public class ApiObject {

                @SerializedName("name")
                private String name;
                @SerializedName("message")
                private String message;
                public ApiObject(String user_name, String message) {
                    this.name = user_name;
                    this.message = message;
                }
                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }
                public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                }
                public String getMessage() {
                    return message;
                }
                public void setMessage(String message) {
                    this.message = message;
                }
            }
                // php file : 
                <?php
                // include Marei DB Class 
                include 'DB.php';
                // get content input and create json object to parse it
                $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
                $obj = json_decode($data);
                // create db instance to use marei db queris 
                $db = DB::getInstance();
                // set type of header response to application/json for respone 
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                if(!$_GET["name"]) {

                 print json_encode(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Username is Non !']);

                }else{

                    print json_encode(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Username is Don !']);   
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: What does your response JSON look like? It seems that you are expecting a JSON array but are getting a JSON object instead.

Comment: bro, you are using List<ApiObject> in retrofit while your response is just ApiObject.
Try response.body().message()

Comment: see here  it's takes me thes massage :msg: error loading from API java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: It performs this function :onFailure , but it can't to performs onResponse

Comment: This means youre JSON deserializer is expecting a JSON Array but found a JSON object instead. What class are you using in your response? Its not matching the actual response JSON.

Comment: Use only that  ApiObject